# Time taken to traverse distance, respecting acceleration and decceleration

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am working on project simulating vehicle transport.
My current function that calculates time required to get from A to B is simple

$time = dist/speed$

I need to change this function, so that it will account for acceleration and decceleration. I found some solutions, that work if the car is allowed to get to full speed, but I also need to account for the cases in which the distance is too short to attain maximum speed. I know ,this question is little bit below math.stackexchange difficulty, and I'm sorry for that, but I do not have slightest idea where to start.  If you can point me in the general direction of the solution, I would be extremely grateful.

Comment: This system of integral equations will relate position and acceleration $$x = x_0 + \int_0^t v(\tau)\,d\tau \\ v = v_0  + \int_0^t a(\tau)\,d\tau$$

Comment: Your nickname perfectly reflect my state of mind upon learning the fact that I need to solve system of Integral equations each time I want to calculate time needed to travel specific distance. :). Thank you nonetheless. I have reading & learning to do.

Comment: To help you simplify the equations from @Bye_World , you need to specify which assumptions can be made. Is the acceleration and/or deceleration assumed to be constant? Is each always assumed to be at most a given value? Etc.

Comment: Acceleration, Decceleration, Max speed are constants, only variable is the distance.

Comment: @semtexzv If $a$ is constant then $v=v_0 + \int_0^t a(\tau)\,d\tau = v_0 + at$ and $x=x_0 + \int_0^t v(\tau)\,d\tau = x_0 + \int_0^t (v_0 + a\tau)\,d\tau = x_0 + v_0t+\frac 12at^2$.  So the relationship between $x$ and $a$ is simply $x = x_0 + v_0t+\frac 12at^2$.

Comment: @semtexzv Either acceleration or deceleration occurs. Right?

Answer (score 0):

A vehicle must travel a distance $D$ and we wish to find the time it takes $T$ with the following assumptions:

a) The vehicle starts at rest and must end at rest

b) It accelerates at a constant rate $a$ and decelerates at a constant rate $d$ ($d$ is negative)

c) When (or if) it achieves its maximum speed $V_{max}$ it cruises at this speed until it must decelerate

Two formulas used in the following: $$V_{final}=V_{initial}+at$$

$$s=V_{initial} \, t+ \frac{1}{2}at^2$$

where $V$ is speed, $t$ is time and $s$ is distance.

Let's call $V_1$ the vehicle's speed after accelerating for a time $t_1$. As it starts at rest, we have $$V_1 = at_1$$

Let's call $V_2$ the vehicle's speed after decelerating for a time $t_2$. As it ends at rest, we have $V_2 = 0$, which means $$0= V_1 + dt_2$$

Combining these two equations we get $$t_2= -\frac a d t_1$$

Now let's look at the distances covered. For the acceleration phase we find $$s_1=\frac{1}{2}at_1^2$$

and for the deceleration phase we find $$s_2=V_1t_2+ \frac{1}{2}dt_2^2$$

Inserting the equation for $t_2$ found above, we can convert the last equation to $$s_2=-\frac{1}{2}\frac{a^2}{d}t_1^2$$

Let's assume for the moment that the vehicle never reaches $V_{max}$. This means there is only an acceleration phase and a deceleration phase. Which means $D = s_1 + s_2$. Which means $$D = \frac{1}{2}at_1^2(1- \frac a d)$$

Extracting $t_1$ from this equation we find $$t_1 = \sqrt{\frac{2D}{a(1-\frac a d)}}$$

We are now ready to give the final answers. Using $t_1$ above, calculate the speed achieved during the acceleration phase ($V_1=at_1$) and compare it with $V_{max}$.

**1. $V_1 \lt V_{max}$**

We are done. The vehicle never reaches its maximum speed and $$T = t_1+ t_2$$

**2. $V_1 \ge V_{max}$**

The vehicle does reach its maximum speed. The time it takes to reach this speed will be $$t_{max}=\frac{V_{max}}{a}$$

This means the distance it covers during the acceleration and deceleration phases will be $$s = \frac{1}{2}at_{max}^2(1- \frac a d)$$

The time it spends cruising at $V_{max}$ must then be $$t_{cruise}=\frac{D-s}{V_{max}}$$

Giving the total time as $$T = t_{max}(1- \frac a d)+ t_{cruise}$$

Answer (score -1):

If uniform acceleration (or deceleration) , start (or end) speed are known then we have time $t$

$$ t = (v-u)/a = (\sqrt {2 a s + u^2}-u)/a $$

where $u,v$ are speeds at start and end. If $a>=<0$ or positive acceleration, then  $ v>=<u. $

Comment: What is $v$ and $u$? You also don't seem to account for different rates of acceleration and deceleration. Or whether a vehicle reaches its max speed or not.

Comment: Nowhere did OP talk about jerk.

Comment: "Jerk"? Your comment is not understood.

Comment: Rate of change of acceleration.

Comment: The rates don't change. but the rate of acceleration may be different from the rate of deceleration.